# MSCRM Opportunity Entities Reassigning Ownership

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have an issue in MSCRM where opportunities are being reassigned to a different owner. It's always the same owner that it gets assigned to and I can not see any workflows or plugins that do the reassigning.

Looking at the audit I can see the user that is doing the reassign is our support user which a lot of workflow use as their owner.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? What else can I look at where the issue might be happening?

Comment: Do you have cascade behavior in oppty relationship? May be the reassignment of owning account/contact/lead/any parent record can trigger this reassignment..

Comment: @ArunVinoth By golly I think you got it :P Can you please add your comment as an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any cascade behavior in opportunity relationship?

May be the reassignment of owning account/contact/lead/any parent record can trigger this reassignment.